# How to refer xml style from Jetpack Compose Modifier?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How do I reference a resource style from Compose widget?

`styles.xml`

```xml
<style name="Style.Monet.TextView.HeaderSubtext" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#737373</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">24dp</item>
</style>
```

`MyComponent.kt`

```kotlin
Text(text = "June 2021", style = TextStyle(R.style.Style_TextView_HeaderSubtext))
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that, because Compose `Text` is styled differently, and `TextStyle` it not responsible so all xml style is responsible. As an example, you cannot add margins.

You can create compose `TextStyle`:

```
val textStyle = TextStyle(
    color = Color(0xFF737373),
    fontSize = 12.sp,
)
```

And use it globally in your project or pass to your theme. This is a preferred way to use styles in compose, check out more about it in the [theming documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes). Customize one of material available styles:

```
val typography = Typography(
        body1 = TextStyle(
                color = Color(0xFF737373),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
        )
)
```

Pass it to your theme:

```
@Composable
fun ComposePlaygroundTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkThemeColors
    } else {
        LightThemeColors
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = shapes,
        content = content,
    )
}
```

Apply Theme at the composable root:

```
setContent {
    ComposePlaygroundTheme {
        // your composables
    }
}
```

After that you can use it like this:

```
Text("",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
)
```

---

To apply margins in compose you need to use padding modifier. Check out more about layout in compose in the [layout documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics):

If you wanna reuse same styled text in compose, you can create your own composable with predefined style and padding:

```
@Composable
fun ProjectText(text: String, modifier: Modifier) {
// without material theme you can just define text style here and pass to text
//    val textStyle = TextStyle(
//        color = Color(0xFF737373),
//        fontSize = 12.sp,
    )
    Text("",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 24.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
ProjectText("June 2021")
```